# Referencing ConsoleApplication from Windows Store App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, console-application

I have created 2 projects, blank windows store app and Console Application.

The problem is when I try to reference Console Application from Windows Store app.

As you can see from the screenshot that there is error popup saying
"Unable to add a reference to project 'ConsoleApplication1'".

1. Why is this error appearing ?
2. How to fix this problem ?

[image: Error when trying to add Console Application reference]

Comment: I don't see that it makes sense to try to add a reference to a console application from a Windows Store app.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The short answer is you can't do this. Windows Store apps do not work like traditional desktop application, they run inside sandboxed environment,  can't communicate with desktop. A Windows Store app is allowed to use a specific set of .NET API, but not allowed to call  desktop APIs like `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`, that is why you can't reference the Console application.